# How can you console.log only the top 100 lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering if there was some sort of .head() equivalent for console.log in JavaScript. I want to log only the first 100 lines of a response to my terminal, but the problem is that the entire object is always printed and the top part consequently gets cut off.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, you'll have to count the lines and stop the printing with a condition

Comment: console only prints what you pass it. grab that full data, cut it up, put it in an array, only print the first X lines of that array

Comment: You can put a breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

Not a node specific solution but you can pipe the result of running your script to `more`. This way only text equal to your screen will be outputted and then you can continue manually to next lines

```
node file_that_outputs_many_lines.js | more
```

Comment: Thank you! This should be the top answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are loging big json file try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(bigfileJson).substring(0,50))
```

soit will log first 50 chars

Answer (score 0):

You can try console.group() this would help. For other console object usage check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console).